# How to put authentication on hapi-swagger documentation page so that only authentic user could see my documentation

Tags: node.js, authentication, swagger, basic-authentication, hapi.js

I am making API with **hapi-swagger** and I have implemented basic-authentication. But even if user doesn't have authentication he can still view my **documentation page**. I want to prevent him from viewing my **documentation page**. How can I implement basic auth on swagger documentation page?
[I want to hide this page and ask for authentication credentials before rendering documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukx5I.png)

Comment: I have same question even I am stuck with this issue from very long time. Why not you just contact developer at github ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
const server = new Hapi.server({ port: process.env.port || 3005, host: "localhost" });
server.ext('onRequest', (req, h) => {

    const route = req.url.pathname;
    if (route === "/documentation") {
        let user = basicAuth(req);
        if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== 'username' || user['pass'] !== 'pwd') {
            return h.response("Unauthorized")
                .code(401)
                .header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Node"')
                .takeover()

        }
    }


    return h.continue;
});
const startServer = async () => {
    await server.register([
        require('@hapi/vision'),
        require('@hapi/inert'),
        {
            plugin: require('hapi-swagger'),
            options: {
                info: {
                    title: 'Doc',
                },
                schemes: ["http", "https"],
                securityDefinitions: {},
                security: [],

            }
        }]);
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
startServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property [`auth`](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/blob/master/optionsreference.md) on plugin registration.

Eg.

```js
    await server.register([
        {
            plugin: require('hapi-swagger'),
            options: {
                auth: 'my-oauth-strategy',
            }
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to set property auth on plugin registration.

> Eg.
>
> ```
> await server.register([
>     {
>         plugin: require('hapi-swagger'),
>         options: {
>            auth: 'my-oauth-strategy',
>        }
>   }]);
> ```

I was not able to understand how `auth`
option work from the docs.

In case your API has already an authentication protocol and functions, how can be these integrate to the hapi-swagger and swagger-ui ?

Let's say your endpoint use a token sent in a specific header, how can you add the same logic to the documentation endpoints ? Is it possible to run a function on the request and its context before to reply with the docs ?